# How to get the parent directories and put them in the list in Python

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, filepath, subdirectory

Is there any way in Python that I can get the parent directories and stores them in the list?

Let's say I have a filepath (`dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`), and what I want is remove `dir4` and add it into my list and delete `dir3` and add again (like recursively).

Below is what I have so far.  I know how to slice filepath (leaf-directory) but I don't know how to store the sliced filepath into the list.

```
Mylist =[]

# return file path of the parent (e.g: dir1/dir2/dir3  ==> dir1/dir2)
def getParentpath(path):
    return "/".join(path.split("/")[:-1])

def checkParentsAndCreate(filepath):
    if not repository.exists(filepath): # check the path is already there?
        checkParentsAndCreate(getParent(filepath)) 
        try:
            repository.create(factory.configurationItem( filepath,'core.Directory'))
        except:
            print 'Unable to create Folder ', filepath
    else:
        # file path is exist, 
        # Need to create folder/path(that I sliced, items in Mylist, in order)...
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused regarding your question. Do you wish to just split the path and add all parts to the list?

Comment: So the final goal is to create the whole directory chain? You could use `os.makedirs(filepath)` for that (`import os` first - at the begining of your file).

Comment: @CristiFati, Thanks for your comment. Honestly, I can't use os.makedirs function because the folder that I am creating is on the server, so I need to use the repository.create() in order to create a folder.

Comment: @Bharel, Thank you for your information.  Sorry about my English. Yes, that is what I wanted to do: splitting the path and add all paths to the list one by one) so that I can recreate the folder in order in my server later. So, I am just wondering if you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.